# javascript class object properties as call back functions

Tags: javascript, class, object, properties, callback

I am writting some javascript class code, which will accept array of 'Steps' objects, and will perform steps navigations.

What I am planning to do is , whenever Next() method is called, it should call a callback function before going to next step.

pseduo code

```
var mySteps = {[1,"Step1","javascriptCallbackStep1"],[2,"Step2","javascriptCallbackStep2"]};
var StepsManager.Next = function() {
  var step = getcurrentStep();
  if(step.javascriptCallbackStep1())
      //go next
}
```

this javascriptCallbackStep1 is not getting called, any help with this little details will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

**[Update:Answer]**
I think I didnt ask it properly.

What I was trying to do was passing function name as string to javascript class property , and expecting it to be called.

```
passedValue = "MyFunctionName";
Class.Validate = passedValue;
```

And then finally for calling it was trying soemthing like below

```
Class.Validate();
```

Offcourse it was not working as in Class.Validate there was string, and there was no specification that treat it as function and not string.

So I successfully tried following

```
Class.Validate = function () { return window[passedValue](); };
```

It worked. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Would you mind posting the actual (relevant) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript needs to be given a reference to a function to execute it. Passing the function itself or doing what @paul suggests is the surest way to write code that acts predictably/reliably.

You shouldn't be passing the function name as a string, but know that you can:

```
function someFunction(name) { return "hello " + name; }
var fn = window["someFunction"]; 
console.log(fn("test"))
```

Change *window* to the namespace where the function lives

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
var mySteps = {
    [1,"Step1", javascriptCallbackStep1 ],
    [2,"Step2", javascriptCallbackStep2 ]
};

var StepsManager.Next = function() {
    var step = getcurrentStep();

    if(step[2]())
    //go next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `step` is an array, and doesn't have a `javascriptCallbackStep1` method. Try this:

```
var mySteps = {
    {id:1,name:"Step1",callback:javascriptCallbackStep1},
    {id:2,name:"Step2",callback:javascriptCallbackStep2}
};
var StepsManager.Next = function() {
  var step = getcurrentStep();
  if(step.callback && step.callback())
      //go next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I didnt ask it properly.

What I was trying to do was passing function name as string to javascript class property , and expecting it to be called.

```
passedValue = "MyFunctionName";
Class.Validate = passedValue;
```

And then finally for calling it was trying soemthing like below

```
Class.Validate();
```

Offcourse it was not working as in Class.Validate there was string, and there was no specification that treat it as function and not string.

So I successfully tried following

```
Class.Validate = function () { return window[jsValidationCallBack](); };
```

It worked. Thank